# Is there a way to delete Opportunity where BPF instance is deleted?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a business process flow on dynamics online for the entity Opportunity. When I delete the instance of BPF, the Opportunity is not been deleted. I need this functionality.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean? deleting BPF instance or BPF altogether ?

Comment: @ArunVinoth i mean, deleting the instance

Comment: so normally we wont allow users to delete, mostly to deactivate. For some business reasons, you are using it as trigger - then try registering plugins against that entity message to achieve what you want.